# How to display magento site or setup page instead of showing the directory. I have shared screenshot

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, magento2, magento-1.4

[image]

I am quite new to php and magento development. I am using apache2 as web server.
I have installed the magento 2 in magf directory of var/www/html
when I entered http://localhost/magf/ in the browser , its showing the directory not the site or installation page.
Spend many hours and followed tutorials but no solution until now.

Answer (score 2):

Since Magento 2.3.6 the setup wizard has been deprecated as per [Magento documentation](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/system/web-setup-wizard.html#:%7E:text=The%20Web%20Setup%20Wizard%20is,Magento%2C%20as%20well%20as%20extensions.) so you won't have the installation page if you are using a newer version.

With the new version of Magento the only way to [install it is via CLI](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli.html?_ga=2.176767264.466130912.1613235050-1414907894.1600164803)

[Example:](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli.html#install-cli-example)

```
$ bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magf/pub/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=es-host.example.com \
--elasticsearch-port=9200
```

Once your application is installed, with your current apache configuration, you should be able to see the site going to the pub/ folder.

**Note**: Since Magento 2.4 you also need to have elasticsearch somehow installed on your hosting setup.

Comment: your answer is not up to date, not working.

Comment: @Y.JoyCh.Singha What do you mean it's not working. Can you specify?